# Store photos in mysql database with iOS app

Tags: ios, mysql, objective-c, file-upload

I am looking for a how to create a mysql database with the photos which are uploaded by my iOS app.

I have already programming the picker and the upload part, but I have no idea how to create this database considering that will have 3 different voices "localization , type , date ".

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean a database on the iPhone? If on your iPhone, the typical solution is sqlite. I personally use an Objective C wrapper, [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb) for that, that gets you out of the weeds of sqlite programming. Or check out [Core Data](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html) if you want to be a little more Cocoa about it.

If, as I suspect, you're talking about your server database, then this is probably not the right forum for that question about how to create a server database. You need to be more specific, and include code samples of what you've tried.